# How to call Vue Js methods in Form-wizard or step-validation of jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js

I used direct link of vue js and i want to call onchange method when i select option from dropdown. It's working fine when i put select tag out of wizard-form / steps-validation. When i put in in the wizard form or step form vue methods are not calling. I can access vue data but not access vue methods.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="wizard-form steps-validation" id="form">
<div id="calculation">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Demo: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                    <select name="country" data-placeholder="Select country" class="form-control form-control-select2" data-fouc  v-model="country" v-select="country" @change="onChange($event)">
                            <option value="1">India</option>
                                <option value="2">USA</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
</form>
```

```
<script>
Vue.directive('select', {
    twoWay: true,
    bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
        $(el).select2().on("select2:select", (e) => {
            el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { target: e.target }));
        });
    },
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#calculation',
    data: {
        country: ''
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.onChange();
    },
    methods: {
        onChange(event) {
            console.log('called change method');
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: please add your tried code to the question

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, the solution for you is [.native](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85) event modifier